# ExtJs 4.1.1 Checkbox is rendering as button, need normal check box

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs4

I am using ExtJs 4.1.1 and want to render normal checkbox to be rendered in a div, but with following code it is rendered as button. I checked ExtJs source for Ext.form.field.Checkbox and in that found a comment for `fieldSubTpl` property which says that

```
// Creates not an actual checkbox, but a button which is given aria role="checkbox" (If ARIA is required) and
// styled with a custom checkbox image. This allows greater control and consistency in
// styling, and using a button allows it to gain focus and handle keyboard nav properly.
```

If this is the case then what is a way to get normal checkbox?

```
 Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',{
            id: 'myContainer',
            width: 100,
            renderTo: 'chekboxId',

            items: [{
                 xtype:'checkboxgroup',
                 id:'chekcboxGrpId',
                 items:[
                    {

                         boxLabel: 'Text check box',                     
                     name : 'MyCheckBox',
                     inputValue: 'true',
                     checked: true

                    }

                 ]

            }]
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't include css/images into your project
[here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahcpd/1/)

css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/try/extjs/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css">
```

HTML

```
    <div id="checkbox"></div>
```

Javascript

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        items: {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'Toppings',
            defaultType: 'checkbox',
            items: [
                {
                    boxLabel  : 'Anchovies',
                    name      : 'topping',
                    inputValue: '1',
                    id        : 'checkbox1'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    panel.render('checkbox');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also figured out same issue.